# Showing $\sum_{v \in V} \deg(v)^2 \in O(m^2/n)$

Tags: inequality, graph-theory, asymptotics, jensen-inequality

Given an undirected graph $G = (V,E)$, where $|V| = n$ and $|E| = m$, I am trying to show that $\sum_{v \in V} \deg(v)^2 \in O(m^2/n)$.

Using Jensen's inequality, we can show that $$\sum_{v \in V} \deg(v)^2 \geq n \left(\frac{1}{n} \sum_{v \in V} \deg(v) \right)^2 = 4m^2/n \in \Omega(m^2/n),$$ however, since $f(x) = x^2$ is convex (and not concave), I can't use Jensen's inequality to show the upper bound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not true. Take a star graph on $n$ vertices, which has $m = n - 1$ edges, which makes $m^2/n = \Theta(n)$. However:

$$\sum \text{deg}(v)^2 = 1^2 + 1^2 + \dots + 1^2 + (n-1)^2 = n(n-1) = \Theta(n^2)$$

Comment: ... and it would appear you are right! The best upper bounds that I can get are $O(m^2)$ or $O(n^3)$, whichever is smallest.